# Using middleware in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware, laravel-5.3

I'm attempting to create a middleware in Laravel 5.3 that checks to see if the user is an admin so I can restrict some routes to admins only.

My Middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class IsAdmin
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( !\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin') ) {
            return redirect('login');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I register it in the Kernal, adding ti to the protected like the below:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
     ....
     'isadmin' => App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
]
```

Then I try to secure my route with:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController')->middleware('isadmin');
```

But I get the error from my route file:

```
FatalThrowableError in web.php line 103:
Call to a member function middleware() on null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply middleware with [`::group()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-middleware):

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'isadmin'], function () {
    Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `UserController` constructor you can use:

```
$this->middleware('isadmin');
```

Docs - [Controller Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#controller-middleware)